# Pytest Monkeypatch package native instance method

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I am trying to use pytest and monkeypatch to unit test a method that has uses a third party data integration package.

Here is some example pseudo code:

```
from third_party.data_integration import Account

def fetch_data():
    account_id = "123"
    account_token = "234"

    account = Account(account_id, account_token)
    account.download('path')
    return True
```

I am hoping to do some like blow in my test file to monkeypatch the `download` instance function:

```
def test_fetch_data(monkeypatch):

    def download():
        return '123'

    with monkeypatch.context() as m:
         m.setattr('third_party.data_integration.Account.download', download)
         assert fetch_data() == True
```

Obviously, `m.setattr('third_party.data_integration.Account.download', download)` would only work for static method instead of instanced method or class method. What is the best practice to do test like this to monkey patch a third party native package instance method?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're calling the constructor of the `Account` class & the method you want to mock is an attribute of the return value of that constructor, you need to mock the return value of the constructor and then monkeypatch the `download` attribute of the mock.

Here's how I would do it:

```
@mock.patch('third_party.data_integration.Account')
def test_fetch_data(mock_account):

    def download():
        return '123'
    acc = MagicMock()
    acc.download = download
    mock_account.return_value = acc
    assert fetch_data() == True
```